# cmd + s is crashing android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

CMD + S was perfectly working for me to save the screenshots from android emulator (API 29 and 30). Recently I have updated my mac to Big Sur, although I am not sure what is the reason?

Does anyone face this issue or know how to solve this issue?

** Tried restarting everything, but didn't work.